# DWM, how to not render a window?

Tags: c++, windows, bitmapimage, hwnd, dwm

My application is a fullscreen window rendering a specified window or the desktop.
I would like to know if it's possible to fetch the window bitmap (like i'm already doing) but without the render of my window's application ?

There is the idea : dwm.giveBitmapWithoutRendering(HWND myApplicationHandler)

Working on Windows 7/8/8.1, QTCreator C++ MINGW

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PrintWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx) with your own memory DC. The success of this method will depend on how the window and its child windows have implemented the `WM_PRINT` message.

This doesn't use DWM but rather gets the window to repaint itself. Since it's not repainting to the screen I hope it meets your requirements.